# How to create a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataset

I am using the playerStat.csv which includes 8 columns from which I only need 2. So I`m trying to create a new DataFrame with only those 2 columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dataset = pd.read_csv("HLTVData/playerStats.csv")
dataset.head(20)
```

[image]

I only need the ADR and the Rating.

So I first create a matrix with the data set.

```
mat = dataset.as_matrix()
#4 is the ADR and 6 is the Rating
newDAtaSet = pd.DataFrame(dataset, index=indexMatrix,columns=(mat[:,4],mat[:,6]) )
```

But it didn`t work, it threw an exception

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-1f975cc2514a> in <module>()
      1 #4 is the ADR and 6 is the Rating
----> 2 newDataSet  = pd.DataFrame(dataset, index=indexMatrix,columns=(mat[:,4],mat[:,6]) )
      

NameError: name 'indexMatrix' is not defined
```

I also tried using the dataset.

```
newDataSet = pd.DataFrame(dataset, index=np.array(range(dataset.shape[0])), columns=dataset['ADR'])

/home/tensor/miniconda3/envs/tensorflow35openvc/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in _make_na_block(self, placement, fill_value)
   3984 
   3985         dtype, fill_value = infer_dtype_from_scalar(fill_value)
-> 3986         block_values = np.empty(block_shape, dtype=dtype)
   3987         block_values.fill(fill_value)
   3988         return make_block(block_values, placement=placement)

MemoryError:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need parameter `usecols` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("HLTVData/playerStats.csv", usecols=['ADR','Rating'])
```

Or:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv("HLTVData/playerStats.csv", usecols=[4,6])
```